# How to calculate x and y variance values?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, kernel-density, gme

I'm trying to define the best suitable cell size to use in the kernel density estimation in the Geospatial Modelling Environment (GME) for ArcGIS.

To calculate the best suitable cell size the following is advised (somewhere else):

> A cell size that is too small will result in a very large output
>   raster ... that takes a long time to calculate. I suggest the
>   following rule of thumb to calculate a reasonable bandwidth: take the
>   square root of the x or y variance value (whichever is smaller) and
>   divide by 5 or 10 ...

So, how should I proceed to the the x and y variance values?

All the best
HNL